# Batch Script doesn't copy to Autostart

Tags: batch-file

My batch should solve a issue, but it doesn't quite work. I think it's simple, i just don't see it. I know it needs Admin, but i shortend the code to where the problem actually is.

```
copy "Data\invisble.vbs" "%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
cd "%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
start invisble.vbs
cls
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code it's hard to know the context.

Please note that the `%appdata%` environment variable changes for each user.

Also note that `copy "Data\invisble.vbs"` specifies a relative path.

The easiest way to pinpoint the issue is to open up a command prompt and run each line and verify the results.

Comment: I would add the full code, but stackoverflow doesn't allow it. I post it here https://jpst.it/-OFe